# Multi-level subfolders for controllers in CodeIgniter 2.x

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-2

I found this post: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/129469/ on CodeIgniter's website on how to handle multi-level subfolders in CI 1.7.1, but CI 2.x has changed the way they do things.  Could someone please point me in the right direction on how to make the changes I need to to get this script to work.  I couldn't follow the comments below the old code.  I posted on CI's forums, but I thought I would try on here to see if someone on here could help out as well.  I'd greatly appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: Post what you've tried, what you expected, and what the actual outcome was. Till then -1.

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/190563/

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to add some order to your controllers, I would recommend modular extensions. It allows you to organize your controllers. models and views in a more logical order.

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Modular_Extensions_-_HMVC